# Why is the Poisson bracket a commutator?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A commutator in abstract algebra, especially group theory, is defined as $$[g,h]=g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$$
The Poisson bracket for two functions $(f(p,q)$ and $g(p,q))$ is defined as:
$$\{f,g\}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}-\frac{\partial f}{ \partial p}\frac{\partial g}{\partial q}$$

How are these definitions connected?
I know that we operate in a symplectic space but how is the operation of "inverse" connected with the operation of "derivation" in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated commutator of a Lie group is the "bracket" for a *Lie algebra*, which is $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. The bracket for a Poisson *algebra* (not group), is therefore of this form. It involves, however, another product on the same vector space. This is also the case for *post-Lie algebras*, where we have a bilinear product $x\cdot y$ on $V$, together with a Lie bracket on $V$, such that the left multiplications $L(x)y=x\cdot y$ are derivations for the Lie bracket.